# JPA Foreign Key Not being Set in @OneToOne

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, one-to-one

I have a @OneToOne relationship mapped. I can get records and see the relationship but I have not been able to create a record and have the foreign key persist. Currently, When a new record gets created in the parent table (FacilityGeneral) I also create a new record in the ChildTable(FacilityLocation), however, the foreign key in the child table does not get created automatically.

```
@Entity
public class FacilityGeneral {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "facilityGenIdSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "facilityGenIdSeq", initialValue = 567, allocationSize = 1)
@Column(updatable = false, unique = true)
private Long generalIdPk;

@NotBlank(message = "Facility Name is required")
private String facilityName;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "facilityGeneral", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JsonIgnore
private FacilityLocation location;
}


@Entity
public class FacilityLocation {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "facilityLocationSeq", initialValue = 374, allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "facilityLocationSeq")
@Column(updatable= false, nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long locationIdPk;

@OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn (name="facilityIdFk")
private FacilityGeneral facilityGeneral;
```

I tried to persist it programmatically by assigning the  sequence value being created as the Primary key in parent table (FacilityGeneral) to a differnt field in the Child table but was unable since the Sequence # isn't generated until the object is persisted. The actual foreign key field remained null.

```
public FacilityGeneral createOrUpdate(FacilityGeneral facility){
    if(facility.getGeneralIdPk() == null) {
        //create new facility
        Number nextInSeq = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT FACILITY_GEN_ID_SEQ.nextval from dual").getFirstResult();
        facility.setGeneralIdPk(nextInSeq.longValue());

        //Create new Records for corresponding relationships
        FacilityLocation location = new FacilityLocation();
        facility.setLocation(location);
        location.setFacilityGeneral(facility);
        //had a none foreignkey field here that I tried to insert to but failed
        //location.setFacilityId(nextInSeq.LongValue());
    }

    return facilityGeneralRepository.save(facility);
}
```

What am I missing in order to populate the foreign key filed (facilityIdFk) automatically with the parent table primary key?

Answer (score 1):

After staring at this for hours I realized that the `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` needed to be `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: you can get more Details Here https://dzone.com/articles/beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-jpa-and

Comment: Thanks @PatelRomil - I'm still alittle confused though. My understanding is that the cascade type PERSIST means that save() or persist() operations cascade to related entities (https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/). Since i was performing a save() operation, I would have thought that this would have worked. Can you provide any insight as to what I overlooked there?

Comment: Can you try with `@MapsId` in Child Entity with CascadeType.PERSIST? 

    @OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn (name="facilityIdFk") @MapsId
    private FacilityGeneral facilityGeneral;